# Calculating mean rate of change with weights

Tags: descriptive-statistics, weighted-mean

Say, I have some data on price of goods sold, quantity and location.

```
g   q    p   l    y
 
g1  4    10  l1   11
g2  8    20  l1   11
g3  40   15  l2   12
g4  67   20  l2   12
g5  100  10  l2   13
g6  43   8   l1   10
g7  25   5   l3   10
```

I'd like to calculate the percentage change in quantity sold `q` for all goods in each location `l` and by year `y`.

By simply calculating the change in `qty` sold, I am losing out on valuable price `p` information. How do I calculate a weighted percent change in quantity sold `q` where weights are `p` ?

And, how do I handle the calculation when I only have 1 observation?

Comment: is q a function of p? Why can't p just be used to model q? did q come from p at endpoint minus p at start? could you model p at outcome instead of q against those variables?